# How to display after 4 week date from now?I want to pass an argument

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-manipulation

```
echo date( "F jS, Y" , strtotime("now +3 weeks") );
```

It gives the result as July 2nd, 2010 .
Fine.Now I want to pass the argument like this.

The original `print_r($originalamount)`
give the result like this

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 4 Months
      [1] => 3500 
)
```

My code

```
 $text=trim($originalamount[0]);
 $text1="now +".$text;

 echo date( "F jS, Y" , strtotime($text1)) ;
```

The out put come like this

```
December 31st, 1969
```

I don't know why.

alt text

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding  echo date( "F jS, Y" , strtotime("now +4 Months") ); to see if ti works?

Comment: Not exactly related, but where does this "4 months" value come from ? wouldn't it be simpler and **safer** to use an integer (number of months/days/whatever) to represent a time duration instead of a plain string ?

Comment: Also, did you try outputting `$text1` before the call to `strtotime()` to see what his value is ?

Comment: ya its work fine for me.Only thing is it produce the error when we applied the argument.

Comment: Hi ereOn I print the value it produce like now +4 Months only.

Answer (score 3):

I have just tried ...

```
$originalamount[0] = '4 Months';

$text=trim($originalamount[0]);
$text1="now +".$text;

echo date( "F jS, Y" , strtotime($text1)) ;
```

And it works fine...

```
October 11th, 2010
```

Can you please give us a var_dump of `$originalamount` is there any other code that might be messing with `$originalamount`

Comment: I tried with different name also.But it wont work
I dont know why.If I hard code it its working fine

Comment: can you var_dump($originalamount); place it right before the trim, also echo `$text` and `$text1` to see if they are what you expected